Java Servlet does not recognize my route/class
I am running a Java servlet using JDK 17, Tomcat 9.0 and Maven on VSCode. I am facing the problem that, when I create a new class to use a new route, Tomcat returns me an Error 404 saying that "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists" even though I added the @WebServlet annotation with the specified route servlet (in context, I should access http://localhost:8080/server/servlet).
This is the project folder structure:
src
└── main
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── example
    │           └── servlet
    │               └── MyServlet.java
    └── webapp
        ├── index.jsp
        └── WEB-INF
            ├── views
            │   └── view.jsp
            └── web.xml

When it is compiled to the /target folder, it is presented this way:
target
├── classes
│   └── com
│       └── example
│           └── servlet
│               └── MyServlet.class
├── generated-sources
│   └── annotations
├── maven-archiver
│   └── pom.properties
├── maven-status
│   └── maven-compiler-plugin
│       └── compile
│           └── default-compile
│               ├── createdFiles.lst
│               └── inputFiles.lst
├── server
│   ├── index.jsp
│   ├── META-INF
│   └── WEB-INF
│       ├── classes
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── example
│       │           └── servlet
│       │               └── MyServlet.class
│       ├── views
│       │   └── view.jsp
│       └── web.xml
└── server.war

I tried to map the servlet route on web.xml, but then Tomcat does not recognize the class (even though I mapped the class right there). So I don't know exactly what is the issue.
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>server</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>server Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>server</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>

web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true"
>
  <display-name> Welcome to Tomcat 9</display-name>
</web-app>

MyServlet.java:
package com.example.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(
      HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/views/view.jsp").forward(request, response);

        // even when it is tested individually (not sending to a JSP file, it does not work
    }
}

INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
[apache-tomcat-9.0.88]: May 05, 2024 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.88]
[apache-tomcat-9.0.88]: May 05, 2024 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Web application installation directory [/home/santiago/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/d8ec3ec1ee17b60fa552c7bbc55f6194/adashen.vscode-tomcat/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.88/webapps/server]
[apache-tomcat-9.0.88]: May 05, 2024 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/home/santiago/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/d8ec3ec1ee17b60fa552c7bbc55f6194/adashen.vscode-tomcat/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.88/webapps/server] has finished in [167] ms
[apache-tomcat-9.0.88]: May 05, 2024 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Web application installation directory [/home/santiago/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/d8ec3ec1ee17b60fa552c7bbc55f6194/adashen.vscode-tomcat/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.88/webapps/ROOT]
[apache-tomcat-9.0.88]: May 05, 2024 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/home/santiago/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/d8ec3ec1ee17b60fa552c7bbc55f6194/adashen.vscode-tomcat/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.88/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [12] ms
[apache-tomcat-9.0.88]: May 05, 2024 10:15:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[apache-tomcat-9.0.88]: May 05, 2024 10:15:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [223] milliseconds

What I am missing to make the servlet new route work properly?

You should post a server log.

@RomanC which kind of log? When I make the request, Tomcat only shows on INFO level. I will edit the post and add them.

By the way, maven.compiler.release replaces the source & target pair. Don’t use all three.

http://localhost:8080/server/servlet — Why are you putting “server” within?

@BasilBourque I created the project via a VSCode Java extension. So I didn't know how the real structure is like.

@BasilBourque "server" is the context name of the project. Just like it shows when I go to http://localhost:8080 and Tomcat shows "War Packages Deployed on this Tomcat Server:" and shows up "server", which leads me to http://localhost:8080/server/.

Tomcat 9.0 uses Servlet spec 4, not 5. See documentation.

Tomcat 9.0 uses javax.* package names, not jakarta.* package names.

By the way, if using Visual Studio Code… FYI: Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code

@BasilBourque I changed to Servlet 4, thanks. I edited the web.xml description in the post. And I switched jakarta for javax now, but I no longer have the @WebServlet annotation import.

As @BasilBourque pointed out, some packages, specifications and tools were not in their correct versions to be ran together.
Because I am using Tomcat 9.0, I had to change jakarta.servlet for javax.servlet instead on pom.xml file.
Also I had to change the Servlet version on web.xml to version 4 instead of version 5, which is probably compatible only with Tomcat 10.0 and above, hence why it was not working properly and finding my route.
The web-app tag on web.xml now is this:
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true">
...

So I removed the @WebServlet annotation on MyServlet.java file and added this to web.xml:
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

And now MyServlet class looks like this, inside src/main/java/com/example/servlet:
package com.example.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

// removed @WebServlet annotation, as there's no import of javax.servlet.annotations on this version (probably)

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(
      HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().write("Hello, World!");
    }
}

As I am using javax.servlet.servlet-api on version 3.0-alpha-1, I guess it has not added the @WebServlet annotation yet on this version, but the 4.0.1 version is here and maybe it already has the annotation.
Now I can access my /servlet route correctly. It was hard to achieve it, because the compatibility of Tomcat with some versions of packages and other stuff is quite esoteric.
UPDATE:
Found out that the @WebServlet annotation was not available because I've set metadata-complete as true on web.xml file. As they are incompatible to coexist, I had to set it to false and the annotation works now:
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="false">

Now I can use @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/servlet") on my class normally.

The @WebServlet annotation is defined in Servlet 3 spec, as noted in the Servlet 4 Javadoc. You should be able to eliminate the web.xml file. And Congrats on your perseverance. Web stack development work is confusing and convoluted.

As an example for your Maven POM file, I used IntelliJ Ultimate 2024.1.1 with its New Project feature with Generators > Jakarta EE > Version > Java EE 8 > Specifications > Servlet (checkbox) to create a project containing a servlet and a JSP.
I ran the web app via the Ultimate edition's feature where it can interact with an external installation of a server like Tomcat.
I am using:

Java 22
Servlet 4.0.1
Tomcat 9.0.88

After a bit of modification by me to update versions and simplify syntax, the following brief Maven POM file succeeds.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExServlet4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExServlet4</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

IntelliJ does create a web.xml file, though it has no meaningful content. I deleted that file, cleaned and rebuilt the project, with my web app continuing to run successfully. While I am not certain, I believe in the modern version of the Servlet specs, they do intend for you to be able to run through annotations alone while skipping the web.xml file entirely.

Thank you for the insight. I created my projects using a Java extension of VSCode, and when I used a Maven archetype for a web app, it created for me a web.xml file that had the <!DOCTYPE> tag and it was set to the 2.3 version, also pom.xml had set the <maven.compiler> properties to JRE 1.7. These two were causing a lot of incompatibilities there with packages and other stuff. Had to search so long to solve them.

@santache (A) As noted at the end of my Answer, I believe you can delete the web.xml entirely. (B) I do not use Visual Studio Code, but if I did I would install the Java extension from Oracle. See announcement article, Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code.

JSP files won't go into WEB-INF; that's not how Eclipse is structured to work. Place JSP files somewhere under WEBAPP which is not WEB-INF.
step 2
stop the server
use annotation with name and url patterns like @WebServlet(name="giveServletClassName",urlPatterns={/url})
and start the server.

Fine, even though I am not using Eclipse.
About step 2: I've set @WebServlet(name = "Servlet",urlPatterns = {"/servlet"}) on my MyServlet.java and it still does not work. Same error, 404.

That’s not how JSP is structured to work.
